# Inverse of natural log

Tags: logarithms

I have a problem:

Let $f(x)=\ln(x)$ solve each of the following equations for $x$.

the question is in three parts

1. $(f(x))^{-1}=5$
2. $f^{-1}(x)=5$
3. $f(x^{-1})=5$

My understanding is that $\ln(x)$ is the same as $\log_e X=\text{exponent}$

So in item $2$ the answer should be $e^5=X$right? which is $148.413\ldots$, but this is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: It is not clear when you mean the inverse function (which would be the exponential function) and when you mean the reciprocal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln(x)$ solve each of the following equations for $x$.

$$f(x)=\ln x$$

$$f^{-1}(x)=e^x$$

$$(f(x))^{-1}=e^x$$

$$f(x^{-1})=\ln(x^{-1})$$

a. $$(f(x))^{-1}=5$$

$$(\ln(x))^{-1}=5$$
$$\ln^{-1}(x)=5$$
$$e^x=5$$
$$\ln(e^x)=\ln(5)$$
$$\ln(5)=x$$

> b. $$f^{-1}(x)=5$$
>
> $$e^x=5$$
> $$\ln(e^x)=\ln(5)$$
> $$x=\ln(5)$$

c. $$f(x^{-1})=5$$
$$f(x^{-1})=\ln(x^{-1})$$
$$\ln(x^{-1})=5$$
$$(-1)\ln(x)=5$$
$$\ln(x)=-5$$
$$e^{\ln(x)} = e^{-5}$$
$$x=\frac{1}{e^{5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\ln^{-1} x = 5
$$
is the same as
$$
e^x = 5
$$
or the same as
$$
x = \ln 5.
$$

(Please don't write $X$ if you mean $x$.  Mathematical notation is case-sensitive.)